# Is there any way to recover a lost Arkham City save?

Tags: xbox-360, batman-arkham-city

A few weeks ago I was one of many people who lost their saved game for Batman Arkham City on the Xbox 360.

I sent an email to WB Support, filling out the incident form they have, and just got a canned response. Has anyone found a way to recover the save files or is it confirmed that recovering the saved games are impossible?

I want to finish it, but I don't want to start from the beginning when I have several other games to play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the save file was deleted or corrupted, then you can't recover it on the xbox360. Because the xbox/ps3/wii are closed systems, you can't directly access save files like you can on a pc.